# Bash script won't stay open in background after running through while

Tags: networking, bash, scripts

I can't get the following bash script to stay open after the first message is received from NC:

```
#!/bin/bash
port=3333
nc -l $port | while read msg; do notify-send Alert "$msg"; done
```

After the first message it exits. I want it to stay open and continue monitoring for new messages from NC.

I know that if I launch `nc -l port` without the while loop it stays open and I can chat away between the two connections even disconnect from the connected host.

I am sending the message using:

```
echo 'done' | nc IP port
```

Comment: It was weird that it didn't work for me. When I put `echo 'done' | nc IP port` on the client, no messages were being shown on the server. I already have added the -k option also. No idea where I went wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a -k option to nc. Like this:

`nc -l $port -k | while read msg; do notify-send Alert "$msg"; done`

As seen in `man nc`:

> -k
>   Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `-k` option. `nc -lk 3333`

As stated by `man nc`

```
 -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current
         connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option without the
         -l option.
```

---

**Edit:**
Notice me and my comrade here posted same answer close to simultaneously. (*Like the mind of that one :)*) – To not be completely redundant I'm adding a sample both using `-k`, and not.

First:

> *I know that if I launch nc -l port without the while loop it stays open and I can chat away between the two connections even disconnect from the connected host.*

This is not the case for me. It closes after one message.

Second:

I'd say `-k`, as it is bundled with the software and works fine, would be the best way to go. However one could also wrap it within an eternal-loop.

Using `-v` to get some more information.

```
#!/bin/bash

nc1()
{
    nc -lkv $port | 
    while read msg; do 
        if [[ "$msg" =~ ^(q|quit|x|exit|halt)$ ]]; then
            printf ";; Received shut down signal \`%s'\n" "$msg"
            # Hack to terminate
            printf "\n" | nc localhost $port &
            break
        fi

        printf "MSG: %s\n" "$msg"
    done
}

nc2()
{
    while true; do
        msg=$(nc -lv $port)
        if [[ "$msg" =~ ^(q|quit|x|exit|halt)$ ]]; then
            printf ";; Received shut down signal \`%s'\n" "$msg"
            break
        fi

        printf "MSG: %s\n" "$msg"
    done
}

port=3333
fun=nc1

while [[ "$1" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    1) fun=nc1;;
    2) fun=nc2;;
    p) port="$2"; shift;;
    *) printf "Unknown option \`%s'\n" "$1"
    esac
    shift
done

$fun
```

And in another session:

```
printf "hello.\nHow are you?\n" | nc localhost 3333; sleep 1; printf "Good bye.\n" | nc localhost 3333; sleep 1; printf "x\n" | nc localhost 3333
```

Going a bit beyond the scope of the question; but could be relevant in some cases:
If you use some dump tool, i.e. `sudo tcpdump -i lo -vvv -w nc.cap` you'll notice that what you get is:

Message "hello.\nHow are you?\n":

```
1. TCP-connection; three-way handshake:

Client send     SYN
Server responds SYN, ACK
Client responds ACK

2. DATA

Client send     ACK, PUSH + message
Server responds ACK

3. TCP-termination; three-way handshake:

Client send     ACK, FIN
Server responds ACK, FIN
Client send     ACK
```